# CSS two span align with border bottom with responsive

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
<p class="section1comments">
<span class="jan">January 20 2011 by David LaHuta in <a href="">A Closer Look</a> </span>
<span class="comments">
<a href="">(1) Comments<sup><img src="slice/comment-icon.jpg" alt="" /></sup></a></span>

</p>
```

**css:**

```
.section1comments, .section2comments {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #747476;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    clear: both !important;
}

.section1comments
{
    width:100%;
}
.jan 
{
    width:79%;
}
.comments 
{
    width: 18%;
margin-left:15px;
}
```

these two span alignment is not working properly when resize the window.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How it is not working properly? explain more Or show your expected output. https://jsfiddle.net/n85a7u2b/

Comment: your fiddle is currect.. but i need t show <span class="comments"> on right side... when i resize the window, it should not change.. but <span class="jan"> should be resize..

Comment: You get that there is a finite amount of space right? Once you start scaling  you will hit break points where stuff has to move to new rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give following css to get your expected result.

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

It will take full width of parent. And `comments` `span` will show on right side when you resize the window.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n85a7u2b/1/)**

**Edit:**

Another option is use `display:table-cell` to span element and `display:table` to it's parent.

```
span {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n85a7u2b/2/)**

Comment: when you resize the window, (1) Comments this line will get in next line right?.. it should not come

Comment: actually, still i  didn't get correct..,, in your last fiddle.. when i resize, comments is changing margin-left right? .. i want to stay stable in right side.. only change on left side span when i resize..

Comment: @selva you mean to say. Comments should not change it's width?

Comment: (1)comments this is one span right?.. this span should not change when i resize..

Comment: @selva Or if you don't want margin-left of comments then give `padding-left`. https://jsfiddle.net/n85a7u2b/3/

Comment: @selva And don't want to resize the width if screen get small. Use `min-width`. https://jsfiddle.net/n85a7u2b/4/

Comment: when i resize your fiddle, like this..  http://s18.postimg.org/83exmvq49/untitled.jpg why it comments shows up..

Comment: @selva. Ohh understood. Add `vertical-align:bottom` to `span`. https://jsfiddle.net/n85a7u2b/5/